# "Im Konflikt sein" vs "im Konflikt stehen"

Tags: phrase, idiom, idiomaticity

Wann sagt man "im Konflikt sein" und wann "im Konflikt stehen"? Beispiele aus dem Netz:

> Kann man mit einer ganzen Gruppe im Konflikt sein?
>
> Kann man im Konflikt mit jemanden sein, der nicht in einem Konflikt mit sich selbst ist?
>
> [Marshall Rosenberg behauptet: Die Bedürfnisse der Menschen -- können nicht im Konflikt sein. Konflikte gibt es nur auf der Strategieebene, also dem, was Menschen wollen.](https://books.google.de/books?id=87A6BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT94&lpg=PT94&dq=%22Marshall+Rosenberg+behauptet:+Die+Bed%C3%BCrfnisse+der+Menschen+k%C3%B6nnen+nicht+im+Konflikt+sein.%22&source=bl&ots=2hpUrqmZ5J&sig=ACfU3U3qC25IpJ8vCGRNFs1f-45UWW9UpA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq8MKhgdbkAhVPr6QKHQX2AJIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Marshall%20Rosenberg%20behauptet%3A%20Die%20Bed%C3%BCrfnisse%20der%20Menschen%20k%C3%B6nnen%20nicht%20im%20Konflikt%20sein.%22&f=false)
>
> Zwei Drittel haben eine Person in ihrem Umfeld, mit der sie regelmäßig im Konflikt stehen.
>
> Dieser Imbiss serviert nur Gerichte aus Ländern, mit denen die USA im Konflikt stehen.

Laut Google tritt die Variante mit *stehen* häufiger auf, aber gibt's evtl. einen Unterschied, etwa im Stil oder in Bedeutung?

Comment: Es gibt auch "Im Widerspruch stehen/sein zu etwas"

Comment: Das Rosenberg-Beispiel ist ohne Kontext unvollständig: Im Konflikt zu was?

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt vielleicht sehr geringe Unterschiede. Das ist, was mir einfällt:

**Erstens** kann man sich einen Konflikt als ein Verhältnis zwischen entgegengesetzten Polen vorstellen, z. B. den kalten Krieg zwischen den USA und der UDSSR.
*Stehen* würde ich dann für die Pole benutzen, d. h.:

> Die USA und die UDSSR standen im Konflikt.

*Sein* würde ich für gleichsam passiv Betroffene benutzen, wie:

> Deutschland war mitten im Konflikt zwischen den USA und der UDSSR.

**Zweitens** würde ich persönlich bei Positionen, Interessen, Prinzipien eher *stehen* verwenden, wie in

> Die Sicherheit steht im Konflikt mit der Kosteneinsparung.

Bei Personen ist beides ungefähr gleichwertig, vielleicht würde ich *sein* häufiger benutzen. Hier geht auch *haben*.

> Peter und Maria haben einen Konflikt. Sie können sich nicht auf eine Farbe einigen.

Comment: Müsste es nicht "in Konflikt stehen" heißen? Die Sicherheit steht in Konflikt mit der Kosteneinsparung?

Comment: @Holger Gute Beobachtung. Die Standardvariante ist *__in__ Konflikt*, würde ich sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Laut meinem Stand des Wissens, gibt es keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden.

Ich persönlich verwende "Im Konflikt sein" öfter.

Comment: I see no semantic difference between both.
But "sein" is been avoided in general as a bad style, so "im Konflikt stehen" sounds more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Heutzutage würde niemand sagen, was regional und archaisch wohl zumindest im Niederländischen bezeugt ist

> ? ich stehe kochen

Jedenfalls drückt *in Konflikt stehen* gewisser Maßen den Stillstand der Situation aus, weniger stark als *bleiben* (vgl Eng. "to stay") es täte. Das ist wohl nicht das Hauptaugenmerk der Floskel. Doch immerhin *liegen* die Kontrahenten nicht im Streit (s. "stehen" als Ausdruck der Kraft).

In Grimm's Wörterbuch findet sich eine schier unendliche Abhandlung des Wortes *stehen*. Einen Hinweis zu einer deutschen Verwendung als Hilfsverb habe ich beim Überfliegen nicht direkt entdeckt, aber Zitate:

> dô entslôʒ man die tür, 
>   diu vil selten dar für 
>   het gestanden ungespart 
>   *Otte Eraclius 3901 Maszmann*
>
> nû ist eʒ (d. land) gar manic zît 
>   in dem jâmer gestanden *krone 19302;*
>
> Leander hat schon lange zeit in dem besten vernehmen mit ihr gestanden *Lessing 1, 351 (misogyn 1, 4);*
>
> die juden gestuonden in nie sô laide *kaiserchr. 10322 Schröder* [als feste Fügung a la *steht dir Gut*, zweimal zitiert, mit Verweis auf Grimms Grammatik]

Auffällig ist, dass viele Floskeln mit der Präposition *in* idiomatisch durch *stehen* ausgedrückt werden: *in Verhältnis, in Bezug zu, in Einklang, im Schatten, in Widerspruch*; s.a. *auf Kriegsfuß*, *zur Seite*, etc. etc.

Natürlich kann man auch sagen, "die Tür *war* selten auf". Grimm legt besonderen Wert darauf zu unterscheiden, dass Süd-Deutsch den Perfektiv "gestanden sein" bildet, während Norddeutsch aus ursächlich Imperfekt heraud "haben" gewohnt ist (s. oben). Ob Ersteres die Fügung mit "sind" bzw. "waren" erleichtert sei dahingestellt.

Bemerke auch, dass *in Konflikt* verwendet wird--vergleiche dazu die Auflistung oben, in der allein *?in Schatten stehen* nicht ohne Artikel funktioniert. Was auch immer das bedeuten mag.

Solange beide Varianten in Konflikt stehen, da Sie Verwendung finden, wird von oben herab nichts daran zu ändern sein. Ich vermute, die Variante mit stehen sei ursprünglich, bei Grimm wird es aber gar nicht erwähnt. Wegen unterschiedlich möglicher Lesarten einerseits und  der verfestigten Bedeutung des Wortes "Konflikt" als eine unüberbrückbare, fortdauernde Verflächtung widerstreitender Interessen andererseits, wäre ein Ausweichen auf das allgemeingültige Hilfsverb "sein" nur all zu nachvollziehbar. Jedenfalls steht es nicht weniger unspezifisch als "stehen", wie die Notwendigkeit der Nachfrage und die Schwierigkeit des Nachweises zeigen.

Comment: Das anführende Fragezeichen zeichnet unwirkliche Beispiele aus. Das sagt also niemand so, wie es geschrieben steht.

Comment: Natürlich ist das nicht weit verbreitet, zum Glück auch, sonst würden die Leute ständig in völlig unüblicher Redeweise kommunizieren

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin im Konflikt mit mir selbst, ob diese Antwort zur Lösung beiträgt.
Wenn ich ausdrücken möchte, das der Konflikt mich persönlich belastet, dann bin
ich im Konflikt mit meiner Frau, Arbeitgeber, ...

Wenn ich aber ausdrücken möchte, dass es mir um den Inhalt des Konfliktes geht, so stehe ich im Konflikt.

Ich stehe im Konflikt mit meinem Arbeitgeber bezüglich der Arbeitszeiten.

Beides ist zwar möglich, aber m.E. entwickeln sich je nach Verwendung unterschiedliche Geschichten.

Ich stehe mit meiner Frau im Konflikt wegen des Sorgerechts für die Kinder. 
... Väter müssen gleichberechtigt über die Entwicklungen des Kindes entscheiden

Ich bin mit meiner Frau im Konflikt wegen des Sorgerechts für die Kinder. 
... Es ist sehr belastend für mich.

Es ist nur mein Sprachempfinden. 
Ich hoffe dass diese Antwort keinen Konflikt auslöst.

Answer (score -7):

*Im Konflikt **sein**, das **macht** doch keinen Sinn, das existiert nicht **in** Deutsch.

To **be** in conflict with someone, well, that doesn't **make** sense, it doesn't exist **in** German.

Alles klar, woher's kommt? Statt "DAS Netz" als solches zum Referenzpunkt zu machen, solltest du vielleicht dict.cc nutzen. Das wird von Akademiker*innen gemacht. Die übersetzen *to be in conflict with* mit *im Konflikt stehen mit*. Alles andere sind  *Bol-**Locken**. :-)

Comment: This is a language purist answer that is just not true.  It become a part of the German language and therefore it **does** exist in German.